# UI-Grid more than one field per column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, js-xlsx

I need to import an Excel sheet to UI-Grid using JS-XLS in the same column where I retrieve data from database. 
For example, one of the columns is defined as:

```
{ field: 'employee_id', displayName: 'ID', width: "*"}
```

From the sheet, the column I would like to join produces an JSON object named "Person Number". I need the "employee_id" and "Person Number" to be on the same column. Something like:

```
{ field: 'employee_id + Person Number', displayName: 'ID', width: "*"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is 'Person Number'? It seems like it would be a string but you say that it is a JSON object.

Comment: When I want to do something like this, I usually just add it to my data structure that is delivered in the JSON. So, I would have a property called "EmployeeIdPersonNumber" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to deal with this. 
After retrieving the data from the Excel sheet, I made a loop to change the key names of the objects to match the ones I retrieve from the database. Like this:

```
data[i].employee_id = data[i]['Person Number'];
delete data[i]['Person Number'];
```

That way, I always have the same structure and make sure that the import will work with any column ordering in the sheet.

Thanks S. Baggy and tylerwal for commenting!